# Repeating data after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 4 links ( view car, hand car, retrieve car and add car). Every link is load by Ajax. The problem is in (add car), the first time I click submit the data gets recorded in the database once ... when I click (view car) and go back to (add car) and submit the form again it adds the data to the database 3 times. Also when I press (view car) and back to add car and submit the from again it records the data 6 times.

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#viewCar').click(function(){
     $("#show").load('view'); 
});});//end click

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#handCar').click(function(){
        $("#show").load('handcar');
    });//end load

});//end click

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#retrieveCar').click(function(){
        $("#show").load('retrieve');
    });//end load
});//end click

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addCar').click(function(){
      enter code here  $("#show").load('add');
    });//end load
});//end click




$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e)


  {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var postData = $('#cForm').serialize();
            var formURL = 'car/add';





  var LT = $("#LT").val();
            var LN = $("#LN").val();



if(LT == ''|| LN == '')
        {
            console.log('error some form is empty !!');
        }
        else
        {  
            $.ajax({
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function() 
                {
                    $('#cForm').find("input[type=text]").val(" ");
                    console.log('saved !!');
                }
            });
        }
       return null;
    });   //end click

}); //end of ready
```

**car_links.html**

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="li"><a id="viewCar" href="#" >view cars</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a id="handCar" href="#">hand car</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a id="retrieveCar" href="#">retrieve car</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a id="addCar" href="#">add a car</a></li>
</ul>
```

**car_add.html**

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

    <form id="cForm" class="form-horizontal" >

        <?php echo validation_errors();  ?>

        <legend>add a new car</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="LN">License #:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-13">
                <input  class="form-control form-size" type="text" id="LN"  name="LN" value="" /></li>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">    
            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="LT">License Ltr:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-13">
                <input  class="form-control form-size" type="text" id="LT" name="LT" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="Model">Model:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-13">
                <select  class="form-control form-size" name="Model">
                    <option value="Toyota"> Toyota</option>
                    <option  value="Audi"> Audi</option>
                    <option  value="Hundai"> Hundai</option>
                    <option  value="BMW"> BMW</option>
                </select>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">   
           <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="Year"> Year:</label> 
            <div class="col-sm-13">
            <select class="form-control form-size" name="Year">
                <option value="2010"> 2010</option>
                <option value="2014"> 2014</option>
            </select>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-actions btn-action">
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit" value="save" type="button" name="submit">save</button></li>
            <button  class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" name="reset"> Reset </button></li> 
         </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters you have each click function in its own `.ready` function. The `.ready` function is initiated when the page is loaded. If you want the function to load only on a click then you need to place the click function into a function like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#viewCar').click(function() {
        $("#show").load('view'); 
    });

    $('#handCar').click(function() {
        $("#show").load('handcar');
    });

    $('#retrieveCar').click(function() {
        $("#show").load('retrieve');
    });

    $('#addCar').click(function() {
        $("#show").load('add');
    });

    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var postData = $('#cForm').serialize();
        var formURL = 'car/add';
        var LT = $("#LT").val();
        var LN = $("#LN").val();

        if(LT == ''|| LN == '') {
            console.log('error some form is empty !!');
        } else {  
            $.ajax({
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function() {
                    $('#cForm').find("input[type=text]").val(" ");
                    console.log('saved !!');
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

If that doesn't work or is not what you wanted please leave me a comment.

Comment: links are working correctly .. the problem in submit in *add car* when I click add car the form is load, when I click submit it record to database one time, but when I transferring between four links , and go back to add car and fill the form and submitted it record the same data more than one times .. thanks for response.. I hope u understand..

Comment: I think its in ajax problem but I don't know.

Comment: Hi talalalsheri, have you tired to use the code i provided? Also have you tried checking for errors with something like firebug? Firebug will tell help you understand where things are going wrong.